# Text processing in java android

Tags: java, android

I have a file that looks similar to this

```
 12345 one
 12345 two
 12345 three
 .......
```

Question is how can i get all of the values from second row and store them in a String[]
i know how to read file in java just dont know how to cut the second row

Comment: you could do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/285745/584026 and then get the 2nd element (`array[1]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the file line  by new line.

```
String [] names = fileString.split("\n");
```

Answer (score 4):

**1.** Store Each line from the file into an `ArrayList<String>`, **its more flexible than** `String[] array`.

**2.** Then access the line you need by `get()` method of ArrayList

**Eg:**

```
ArraList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

//Now add each lines into this arr ArrayList

arr.get(1);         // Getting the Second Line from the file
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what i did but it skips first line

```
  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/sys..........");

          DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
          String strLine;

          strLine = br.readLine();
          while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {

              delims = strLine.split(" ");
               first = delims[1];
               where.add(first);

          }

          in.close();
```

From example above it contains only "two" and "three"