# what is wrong with this piece of code. keeps printing null

Tags: java

I want to read each line from a file and store each line into an array of strings

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            int i = 0;

            String[] sArray = new String[line.length()];
            sArray[i] += line;
            System.out.println(sArray[i]);

                   i++;
        }
```

output:

```
nullKNZAVM   
nullCPKCCA  
nullKMUAXP
```

why it prints null before each set of letters.

Comment: How do you think this code works? What do you think `String[] sArray = new String[line.length()];` does in each iteration? What happens with it after iteration?

Comment: do ***System.out.println(line)*** instead

Comment: do `sArray[i] = line;` instead; sArray[i]'s default String value is null, that's why null gets printed out

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: What you are looking for is something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12592835.

Comment: If any of these answers have helped you, it is protocol to select one as the accepted answer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **why it prints null before each set of letter**??

you are doing this:

```
 String[] sArray = new String[line.length()];
 sArray[i] += line;
```

so you create an array with a size of line.length() elements but all those elements are not initialized. now since String is an object the default value of a non initialized is `null` so every element in the array is null

doing  `sArray[i]  += line;` is the same as concatenate null to the line...

Answer (score 1):

Because of this line:

```
sArray[i] += line;
```

Since the elements are `null` (as in, undefined or unitialised), when you use the concatenation `+=`, it transforms the value of `null` to a String "null". So you concatenate your line to the string "null", to get the output you're seeing.

If you don't want that, just assign instead:

```
sArray[i] = line;
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you think is in `sArray[i]` before you `+=` the String `line`?

It's null of course!

Try this to see:

```
String N = null;
String M = N + "something";
System.out.println(M);
```

---

Using the the Java String `+=` operator compiles to using `StringBuilder` underneath. But each element is run through `String.valueOf()` first.

And `String.valueOf(null)` returns `"null"` as a String.

So it evaluates to:

```
String N = null;
String M = StringBuilder.append(N).append("something").toString();
System.out.println(M);
```

Which in turn gives you:

```
String M = StringBuilder.append(null).append("something").toString();
```

Which ultimately gives you:

```
String M = StringBuilder.append("null").append("something").toString();
```

---

PS. The assignment of an incorrect length to the array is a separate issue. The length of each String and the length of the array are two different concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do smth like that:

```
int line = 0;
for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
//...
}
```