# How to read .txt file until EOF in java and store into array properly

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
import java.io.File;
```

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MailMessage {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i = 0;
    String condition = "EOF";
    String[] mail = new String[500];
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\sailo\\eclipse-workspace\\mail.txt");
    Scanner mailInput = new Scanner(file);
    while (mailInput.hasNextLine() && i < 500 && condition != "EOF") {
        mail[i] = mailInput.nextLine();
        i++;
        System.out.print(mail[1] + "\n");
    }
}
```

}
[This is what the txt file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPXxY.png)

Comment: `condition != "EOF"` is not the proper way to compare Strings in Java.  Also will not `hasNextLine` already take care of the end of file?  Also `condition ` is assigned the value `EOF` and it never changes.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Ah thank you! It's working now as each indices of the array contains a line. Is there any way I can store the whole paragraph before EOF into each indices though?

Comment: Yeah, try coding it yourself and then come back here if you have trouble.

Comment: Or ... just read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285712